# ¿Por qué mi formulario con subida de imagenes no funciona?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo este formulario que no esta funcionando ya probé el backend con postman y si me funciona pero la subida de imágenes de este formulario no.
creo que el problema puede estar en esta linea

```
const apiEndPoint = apiUrl + '/img';
```

pero no estoy segura...

```js
import React from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import Form from "./common/form";
import { getMovie, saveMovie } from "../services/movieService";
import { getGenres } from "../services/genreService";
import axios from 'axios';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Progress } from 'reactstrap';
import { apiUrl } from '../config.json';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const apiEndPoint = apiUrl + '/img';

class MovieForm extends Form {
    state = {  
        data: {
            title: "",
            genreId: "",
            numberInStock: "",
            dailyRentalRate: "",
            movieImg: { movieImg: null, loaded: 0}
          },
          genres: [],
          errors: {}
    }

    schema = {
        _id: Joi.string(),
        title: Joi.string()
          .required()
          .label("Title"),
        genreId: Joi.string()
          .required()
          .label("Genre"),
        numberInStock: Joi.number()
          .required()
          .min(0)
          .max(100)
          .label("Number in Stock"),
        dailyRentalRate: Joi.number()
          .required()
          .min(0)
          .max(10)
          .label("Daily Rental Rate"),
        movieImg: Joi.string().allow("").optional()
    }

    async populateGenres() {
      const { data: genres } = await getGenres();
        this.setState({ genres });
    }

    async populateMovie() {
      try {
        const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;
        if (movieId === "new") return;

        const { data: movie } = await getMovie(movieId);
        this.setState({ data: this.mapToViewModel(movie) });
      } catch(ex) {
       if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 404) 
        this.props.history.replace("/not-found");
      }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.populateGenres();    
        await this.populateMovie();
    }
    
      mapToViewModel(movie) {
        return {
          _id: movie._id,
          title: movie.title,
          genreId: movie.genre._id,
          numberInStock: movie.numberInStock,
          dailyRentalRate: movie.dailyRentalRate,
          movieImg: movie.movieImg
        };
    }
    
    doSubmit = async () => {
        await saveMovie(this.state.data);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', this.state.movieImg);
      
        axios.post(apiEndPoint, data, {
          onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
              this.setState({
                movieImg: { loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total*100) }
              })
            },
          })
          .then(res => { toast.success('upload success') })
          .catch(err => { toast.error('upload fail') });
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        this.props.history.push("/movies");
    }

    
    onChangeHandler = async event => {
      var image = event.target.image;
    
      this.setState({
        movieImg: {
          movieImg: image, loaded: 0
        }
      });
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className = "container">
              <div className = "height"></div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <ToastContainer />
              </div>
              <div className = "card card-login card-hidden">
              <div className = "card-header card-header-primary text-center">
                <h4>Movie Form</h4>
              </div>
              <form encType='multipart/form-data' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className = "card-body text-center p-4">
                {this.renderInput("title", "Title")}
                {this.renderSelect("genreId", "Genre", this.state.genres)}
                {this.renderInput("numberInStock", "Number in Stock", "number")}
                {this.renderInput("dailyRentalRate", "Rate")}
                <label htmlFor="file" className="btn btn-primary">Choose your file</label>
                <div className="form-group files">
                  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" className="input-file" 
                  multiple onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={this.doSubmit} >Upload</button>
                <div className="form-group my-5">
                <Progress max="100" color="primary" value={this.state.loaded} >{Math.round(this.state.loaded,2) }%</Progress>
                </div>
                {this.renderButton("Save")}
                </div>
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default MovieForm;
```

Comment: Al ejecutarlo te da un error particular? el resultado de `apiEndPoint` es la misma url que usas en postman? (antes de hacer la llamada ajax puedes ponerle `console.log(apiEndpoint);`)

Comment: en postman tengo simplemente `img/1566582953424-Airplane.jpg` por ejemplo y este `apiEndPoint` es `http://localhost:3900/api/img` el error que me da en consola es `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`.